# phpmailer with SMTP server on WordPress: mails with spamscore 8.5/10 don't reach Gmail or Hotmail

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I'm using `phpmailer` with an smtp mail server to send mails on a Wordpress site (a basic contact form). When I send the mail to [mail-tester.com](https://www.mail-tester.com/), it receives a spamscore of 8.5/10, which is good. However, when i send it to a Gmail address or a Hotmail address, both will not be delivered, not even in spam. I've checked the SMTP server, it says the mails have been sent without problems. I've setup SPF records, which seem to be fine according to mxtoolbox. How do I fix this? What steps can I take to find out why Hotmail and Gmail are not receiving my mails?
Thanks!

Comment: what error response are you getting during sending mail?

Comment: None. mail-tester.com receives the mail just fine. Also, according to my SMPT server log, the mails are sent without any problems.